# Need advice to write a simple script that detect one set of process

Tags: bash

I need to write a simple script to run in the background all the time. And its job is to just monitor one form of process say htop process. Say if htop porocess is being trigger or ran, then do something , and when that process exit, also do something. I manage to use while loop in my script to constantly monitor this process in the backgronud. And I have check the cpu usage is around 1.4 %. Now i am not sure if that is bad. I was wondering if anyone has other way to do this.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I have to monitor a background backup/restore RSYNC process.

That script has a **"while [true]" loop**.  It then has a conditional test on whether to exit.

If it is to exit, this is where you could add logic to perform whatever task you want before exiting the script.

If it is to continue, you could add commands to keep track of whether this is the first time in the loop or not, then perform a task accordingly.

How much CPU is used depends on the timing delay specified for each loop before performing another scan for a specified condition.

Listing of script **OS_Admin__partitionMirror_Monitor.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

##########################################################################################################
### $Id: OS_Admin__partitionMirror_Monitor.sh,v 1.3 2022/08/05 03:46:55 root Exp root $
###
### This script is intended to perform an ongoing scan to report when an active RSYNC backup process terminates.
##########################################################################################################

test_STEP1()
{
echo "root        7520    7514 12 20:50 pts/0    00:05:46 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/
root        7514    7512  0 20:50 pts/0    00:00:25 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/
root        7512       1 17 20:50 pts/0    00:08:27 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/" >${TMP}
awk '{ printf("\trsync|%s\n", $0 ) ; }' ${TMP}
echo ""
}

test_STEP2()
{
echo "7520
7514
7512" >${TMP}.pid
awk '{ printf("\t pid |%s\n", $0 ) ; }' ${TMP}.pid
echo ""
}

test_STEP3()
{
echo "7514|7520
7512|7514
1|7512" >${TMP}.ppid
awk '{ printf("\tppid |%s\n", $0 ) ; }' ${TMP}.ppid
echo ""
}



. $Oasis/bin/INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.${BASE}.$$"

date | awk '{ printf("\n\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'

if [ "$1" = "--snapshots" ]
then
    SNAP=1
else
    SNAP=0
fi

rm -f ${TMP}
ps -ef 2>&1 | grep -v grep | grep rsync | sort -r >${TMP}
#test_STEP1


if [ ! -s ${TMP} ]
then
    echo "\t RSYNC process is ${redON}not${redOFF} running (or has already ${greenON}terminated${greenOFF}).\n"
    exit 0
fi

awk '{ print $2 }' <${TMP} >${TMP}.pid
#test_STEP2


awk '{ printf("%s|%s\n", $3, $2) }' <${TMP} >${TMP}.ppid
#test_STEP3


for pid in `cut -f1 -d\| ${TMP}.ppid `
do
    PPID=`grep ${pid} ${TMP}.pid `
    PID=`grep '^'${pid} ${TMP}.ppid | cut -f2 -d\| `
    PRNT=`grep '^'${pid} ${TMP}.ppid | cut -f1 -d\| `
    if [ \( -n "${PPID}" \)  -a  \( "${PRNT}" -ne 1 \) ]
    then
        descr="child"
        echo "\t PID ${PID} is RSYNC ${cyanON}${italicON}${descr}${italicOFF}${cyanOFF} process ..."
    else
        descr="MASTER"
        echo "\t PID ${PID} is RSYNC ${yellowON}${descr}${yellowOFF} process ..."
    fi
done

getRsyncProcessStatus()
{
    testor=`ps -ef 2>&1 | awk -v THIS="${PID}" '{ if( $2 == THIS ){ print $0 } ; }' `
    MODE=`echo "${testor}" |
        awk '{ if( $NF ~ /^[/]DB001_F?[/]/ ){ print "2" }else{ print "1" } ; }' 2>>/dev/null ` 
}

getRsyncProcessStatus

if [ ${MODE} -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "\t RSYNC restore process under way ..."
    INTERVAL=60
else
    echo "\t RSYNC backup process under way ..."
    INTERVAL=10
fi

if [ -n "${testor}" ]
then
    echo "\n\t ${testor}\n" | sed 's+--+\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t--+g' | awk '{
        rLOC=index($0,"rsync") ;
        if( rLOC != 0 ){
            sBeg=sprintf("%s", substr($0,1,rLOC-1) ) ;
            sEnd=sprintf("%s", substr($0,rLOC+5) ) ;
            sMid="\033[91;1mrsync\033[0m" ;
            printf("%s%s%s\n", sBeg, sMid, sEnd) ;
        }else{
            print $0 ;
        } ;
    }'
    echo "\n\t Scanning at ${INTERVAL} second intervals ..."
    test ${SNAP} -eq 1 || echo "\t \c"
fi

if [ ${SNAP} -eq 1 ]
then
    while true
    do
        getRsyncProcessStatus
        if [ -z "${testor}" ]
        then
            echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${PID}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"
            date | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'
            exit 0
        fi
        jobLog=`ls -tr /site/Z_backup.*.err | tail -1 `
        echo "\t `tail -1 ${jobLog}`"
        sleep ${INTERVAL}
    done 2>&1 | uniq
else
    while true
    do
        getRsyncProcessStatus
        if [ -z "${testor}" ]
        then
            echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${PID}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"
            date | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'
            exit 0
        fi
        echo ".\c"
        sleep ${INTERVAL}
    done 
fi


exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```

That script uses a "Bourne Header" script, **INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

##########################################################################################################
### $Id: INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh,v 1.2 2022/09/03 01:57:31 root Exp $
###
### This includes string variables defined to perform various substitutions for the ANSI Terminal Escape Sequences, i.e. SGR (Select Graphic Rendition subset)
##########################################################################################################

### "\e" is same as "\033"

boldON="\e[1m"
boldOFF="\e[0m"

italicON="\e[3m"
italicOFF="\e[0m"

underlineON="\e[4m"
underlineOFF="\e[0m"

blinkON="\e[5m"
blinkOFF="\e[0m"

cyanON="\e[96;1m"
cyanOFF="\e[0m"

cyanDarkON="\e[36;1m"
cyanDarkOFF="\e[0m"

greenON="\e[92;1m"
greenOFF="\e[0m"

yellowON="\e[93;1m"
yellowOFF="\e[0m"

redON="\e[91;1m"
redOFF="\e[0m"

orangeON="\e[33;1m"
orangeOFF="\e[0m"

blueON="\e[94;1m"
blueOFF="\e[0m"

blueSteelON="\e[34;1m"
blueSteelOFF="\e[0m"

magentaON="\e[95;1m"
magentaOFF="\e[0m"

##########################################################################################################
### Usage Examples:
##########################################################################################################

#   echo "\t RSYNC process is ${redON}not${redOFF} running (or has already ${greenON}terminated${greenOFF}).\n"
#   echo "\t ${PID} is ${cyanON}${italicON}${descr}${italicOFF}${cyanOFF} process ..."
#   echo "\t ${PID} is ${yellowON}${descr}${yellowOFF} process ..."
#   echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${pid}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"

##########################################################################################################
### Example of scenario where escape codes are hard-coded; \e was not accepted by awk
##########################################################################################################

#   echo "\n\t ${testor}\n" | sed 's+--+\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t--+g' | awk '{
#       rLOC=index($0,"rsync") ;
#       if( rLOC != 0 ){
#           sBeg=sprintf("%s", substr($0,1,rLOC-1) ) ;
#           sEnd=sprintf("%s", substr($0,rLOC+5) ) ;
#           sMid="\033[91;1mrsync\033[0m" ;
#           printf("%s%s%s\n", sBeg, sMid, sEnd) ;
#       }else{
#           print $0 ;
#       } ;
#   }'

##########################################################################################################
    echo "\n\t Imported LIBRARY:  INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh ..."
##########################################################################################################
```

A snapshot of what is reported when RSYNC is not running:

[image: Behaviour when RSYNC is not detected]

A snapshot of what is reported when RSYNC is running:

[image: Behaviour when RSYNC detected in background]